# .NET application using a Redis database that is running on linux (Virtual Machine)

Tags: .net, linux, winforms, redis

I am building a high performance .NET application which has to process on over 100,000 records at a time. Performance/Speed is my prime concern. I am thinking of using Redis as the database. It is mentioned in the Redis documentation that deploying it over Windows is not officially supported, and should not be used in production.

So is it possible to deploy Redis on a linux distribution that is running on a windows machine using VMWare/HyperV,etc, and then use it from within a .NET application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but you'll suffer a minor blow on performance because you're running unix within a VM, thus you have a *thin* layer (virtualisation) in between your .NET application and the REDIS host.

Some links that you might find useful:

- [Installing a unix image in VM Player](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11287/how-to-run-ubuntu-in-windows-7-with-vmware-player/)
- You'll also need to connect to Redis at some point, so you'll need the VM IP: https://superuser.com/questions/433988/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-a-vm-running-on-vmware-or-other-methods-of-using

*PS: If you plan on going serious with this, just get a simple unix box for the redis server.*